# Deserialization of a json model with @JsonProperty annotation changed attributes with builder pattern

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am writing a shared object **ItineraryDataEntry** that is getting exported in a library other projects use.
Model has a lot of attributes, so I am using a builder pattern approach.
Both me and QA relay on the same object for deserialization but are seeing different input (database returns json as set of field vars, and I am returning transformed json keys from api with a more readable format).

#### BE

1) I am deserializing an object that is saved in an airline database as a json.
Then I am transforming this object's keys with for example **@JsonProperty("origin")** for **field02** and returning **ItineraryDataEntry** as a part of a complex structured json from a Spring controller endpoint.
With this part I have no issues.

#### QA

2) QA team is importing mentioned library and wants to deserialize a response from my API to this same **ItineraryDataEntry** object. This is a problem as Jackson doesn't know how to map for example response property **("origin")** back to **field02**. Solution on their side is for me to add **@JsonProperty("origin")** annotation to the builder variables.

#### !

But adding annotation mention in 2) breaks the deserialization then on my part as I am deserializing a json that is different from what is QA team expecting. I need deserialization working on my part for db tests as well.

How would I achieve to still use a single class with a builder pattern and both different inputs would deserialize properly?
Can I kindly ask for your support, a kind member of this excellent community?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonPOJOBuilder;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Model for Itinerary data item.
 */
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@ApiModel(value = "ItineraryDataEntry")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ItineraryDataEntry.ItineraryDataEntryBuilder.class)
public class ItineraryDataEntry implements Serializable {

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Item type", example = "pnr", allowableValues = "pnr,leg")
  @JsonProperty("type")
  private String type;

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Item field01", example = "62SVBP")
  @JsonProperty("legNumber")
  private String field01;

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Item field02", example = "MASON JAMES MR.")
  @JsonProperty("origin")
  private String field02;

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Item field03", example = "194375957326594")
  @JsonProperty("destination")
  private String field03;

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Item field04", example = "AIRLINE NAME")
  @JsonProperty("carrier")
  private String field04;

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Item field05", example = "Y")
  @JsonProperty("fareBasisCode")
  private String field05;

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Item field06", example = "TRAVEL AGENT NAME")
  @JsonProperty("serviceClass")
  private String field06;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String field07;

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Item field08", example = "050918")
  @JsonProperty("flightDate")
  private String field08;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String field09;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String field10;

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Item field11", example = "1115")
  @JsonProperty("departureTime")
  private String field11;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String field12;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String field13;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String field14;

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(final String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getField01() {
    return field01;
  }

  public void setField01(final String field01) {
    this.field01 = field01;
  }

  public String getField02() {
    return field02;
  }

  public void setField02(final String field02) {
    this.field02 = field02;
  }

  public String getField03() {
    return field03;
  }

  public void setField03(final String field03) {
    this.field03 = field03;
  }

  public String getField04() {
    return field04;
  }

  public void setField04(final String field04) {
    this.field04 = field04;
  }

  public String getField05() {
    return field05;
  }

  public void setField05(final String field05) {
    this.field05 = field05;
  }

  public String getField06() {
    return field06;
  }

  public void setField06(final String field06) {
    this.field06 = field06;
  }

  public String getField08() {
    return field08;
  }

  public void setField08(final String field08) {
    this.field08 = field08;
  }

  public String getField11() {
    return field11;
  }

  public void setField11(final String field11) {
    this.field11 = field11;
  }

  public String getField07() {
    return field07;
  }

  public void setField07(final String field07) {
    this.field07 = field07;
  }

  public String getField09() {
    return field09;
  }

  public void setField09(final String field09) {
    this.field09 = field09;
  }

  public String getField10() {
    return field10;
  }

  public void setField10(final String field10) {
    this.field10 = field10;
  }

  public String getField12() {
    return field12;
  }

  public void setField12(final String field12) {
    this.field12 = field12;
  }

  public String getField13() {
    return field13;
  }

  public void setField13(final String field13) {
    this.field13 = field13;
  }

  public String getField14() {
    return field14;
  }

  public void setField14(final String field14) {
    this.field14 = field14;
  }

  public ItineraryDataEntry(final ItineraryDataEntryBuilder builder) {
    this.type = builder.type;
    this.field01 = builder.field01;
    this.field02 = builder.field02;
    this.field03 = builder.field03;
    this.field04 = builder.field04;
    this.field05 = builder.field05;
    this.field06 = builder.field06;
    this.field07 = builder.field07;
    this.field08 = builder.field08;
    this.field09 = builder.field09;
    this.field10 = builder.field10;
    this.field11 = builder.field11;
    this.field12 = builder.field12;
    this.field13 = builder.field13;
    this.field14 = builder.field14;
  }

  public ItineraryDataEntry() {
  }

  /**
   * The type Itinerary data entry builder.
   */
  @JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "build", withPrefix = "")
  public static class ItineraryDataEntryBuilder {

    private String type;

    private String field01;

    private String field02;

    private String field03;

    private String field04;

    private String field05;

    private String field06;

    private String field07;

    private String field08;

    private String field09;

    private String field10;

    private String field11;

    private String field12;

    private String field13;

    private String field14;

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder type(final String param) {
      this.type = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field01(final String param) {
      this.field01 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field02(final String param) {
      this.field02 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field03(final String param) {
      this.field03 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field04(final String param) {
      this.field04 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field05(final String param) {
      this.field05 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field06(final String param) {
      this.field06 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field07(final String param) {
      this.field07 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field08(final String param) {
      this.field08 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field09(final String param) {
      this.field09 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field10(final String param) {
      this.field10 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field11(final String param) {
      this.field11 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field12(final String param) {
      this.field12 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field13(final String param) {
      this.field13 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder field14(final String param) {
      this.field14 = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder() {
      // prevent init.
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntry build() {
      return new ItineraryDataEntry(this);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Edit: A not ideal solution

I've introduced additional variables thanks to @Coder suggestion.
This mean we can use the same model, and the object is serialized/deserialized like intended.
[QA debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxqvh.png)
I've put @JsonIgnore annotations on this variables so that response model is not changed, but deserialization now works on both sides.

```
...
  @JsonIgnore
  private String legNumber;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String origin;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String destination;

  public String getLegNumber() {
    return legNumber;
  }

  public void setLegNumber(final String legNumber) {
    this.legNumber = legNumber;
  }

  public String getOrigin() {
    return origin;
  }

  public void setOrigin(final String origin) {
    this.origin = origin;
  }

  public String getDestination() {
    return destination;
  }

  public void setDestination(final String destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
  }
...
```

Builder part

```
  public ItineraryDataEntry(final ItineraryDataEntryBuilder builder) {
    this.type = builder.type;
    this.field01 = builder.field01;
    this.field02 = builder.field02;
    this.field03 = builder.field03;
    this.field04 = builder.field04;
    this.field05 = builder.field05;
    this.field06 = builder.field06;
    this.field07 = builder.field07;
    this.field08 = builder.field08;
    this.field09 = builder.field09;
    this.field10 = builder.field10;
    this.field11 = builder.field11;
    this.field12 = builder.field12;
    this.field13 = builder.field13;
    this.field14 = builder.field14;
    this.legNumber = builder.legNumber;
    this.origin = builder.origin;
    this.destination = builder.destination;
    this.carrier = builder.carrier;
    this.fareBasisCode = builder.fareBasisCode;
    this.serviceClass = builder.serviceClass;
    this.flightDate = builder.flightDate;
    this.departureTime = builder.departureTime;
  }
...

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder origin(final String param) {
      this.origin = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder destination(final String param) {
      this.destination = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder carrier(final String param) {
      this.carrier = param;
      return this;
    }
...
```

Comment: Are you looking to store different information for the same variable? I couldn't follow the issue you are referring to. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Hi @Coder it is the same information in variables. But keys are different. For example the input I am deserializing is {type:'leg', field01:'null', field02:'null', field03:'null', ...} and qa is deserializing {type:'leg', legNumber:'null', origin:'null', destination:'null', ...}

Comment: Should QA not get any objects that you are deserializing?

Comment: QA has an app of their own for testing the API itself and we would like to use a shared model. I don't understand the question sorry. I am deserializing an object from a different source than they (in unit tests). They are deserializing essentially the same object but with keys changed. So for Jackson these are two different models and deserialization fails. If I add annotation for jsonProperty on the builder variables itself then deserialization fails for me and works for them. So how to deal with this? Thank you.

Comment: You could use the jsonProperty annotation with the variables that QA is looking for. All you have to do is add those variables to your class. Do you follow?

Comment: Ok, I did it like you suggested and it works. I will edit my question. Essentially I just added those missing variables and annotated them with @JsonIgnore. So the response is not changed, and both me and QA can use the same model. I am not sure if this is the perfect solution, I still believe this should be doable somehow as Jackson is changing the response and should with some instruction know how to build it in the original way.

Comment: On a second thought I see that I misunderstood your answer, but it helped me get to the solution. If I would go and use jsonProperty annotation with the QA variables deserialization would fail on my end when parsing the json from the db.

Comment: Do you want to post your solution so that it will help someone else looking for answers? Either you do it or I will do it. Not everyone goes through comments to find the solution :)

Comment: I've updated the topic with the answer, but yeah I can post a solution in another post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

I've introduced additional variables thanks to @Coder suggestion.
This mean we can use the same model, and the object is serialized/deserialized like intended.
[QA debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxqvh.png)
I've put @JsonIgnore annotations on this variables so that response model is not changed, but deserialization now works on both sides.

```
...
  @JsonIgnore
  private String legNumber;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String origin;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String destination;

  public String getLegNumber() {
    return legNumber;
  }

  public void setLegNumber(final String legNumber) {
    this.legNumber = legNumber;
  }

  public String getOrigin() {
    return origin;
  }

  public void setOrigin(final String origin) {
    this.origin = origin;
  }

  public String getDestination() {
    return destination;
  }

  public void setDestination(final String destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
  }
...
```

Builder part

```
  public ItineraryDataEntry(final ItineraryDataEntryBuilder builder) {
    this.type = builder.type;
    this.field01 = builder.field01;
    this.field02 = builder.field02;
    this.field03 = builder.field03;
    this.field04 = builder.field04;
    this.field05 = builder.field05;
    this.field06 = builder.field06;
    this.field07 = builder.field07;
    this.field08 = builder.field08;
    this.field09 = builder.field09;
    this.field10 = builder.field10;
    this.field11 = builder.field11;
    this.field12 = builder.field12;
    this.field13 = builder.field13;
    this.field14 = builder.field14;
    this.legNumber = builder.legNumber;
    this.origin = builder.origin;
    this.destination = builder.destination;
    this.carrier = builder.carrier;
    this.fareBasisCode = builder.fareBasisCode;
    this.serviceClass = builder.serviceClass;
    this.flightDate = builder.flightDate;
    this.departureTime = builder.departureTime;
  }
...

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder origin(final String param) {
      this.origin = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder destination(final String param) {
      this.destination = param;
      return this;
    }

    public ItineraryDataEntryBuilder carrier(final String param) {
      this.carrier = param;
      return this;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has the answer in itself.

> I am deserializing an object that is saved in an airline database as a json. Then I am **transforming** this object's keys

You ***cannot do it in one step*** and share the same model and perform 2 different deserializations on it. That beats the purpose of model reuse.

Instead, I would suggest having 2 models. One to deserialize into a structure that you could commonly share across teams/projects. Another to map it to a meaningful object like an **ItineraryDataEntry** that will have *type, origin, destination, etc.*. You can then write a separate method in your controller to transform the deserialized object in your meaningful **ItineraryDataEntry**.

I am assuming that your model is deeper than what you have mentioned. In that case, I would suggest exploring **[Orika](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika)** library.

Comment: Is there really no way? I am asking because I am not changing the model itself just that response get's changed with JsonProperty annotation which is a part of Jackson lib. And I am serializing/deserializing the object then again with Jackson. Also having 2 models would mean I would need to have 8 classes duplicated just to include this slightly modified one in it.

Comment: I've solved this with introducing additional variables, so we can reuse the same model.